# Time taken by two Matlab scripts for pixel-wise image processing are different. Why?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colors

I have two Matlab scripts for pixel-wise image processing. Using these both scripts, I am detecting white objects from an image.

**The first script is**

```
tic;
I2 = imread('28.jpg');
II = I2;  
ca = I2(:,:,3) - (I2(:,:,1)/3)- (I2(:,:,2)/3);
for ii = 1:size(I2,1)
    for jj = 1:size(I2,2)
        CA = ca(ii,jj);
        if CA < 30   % to remove black color pixels and others noise
            I2(ii,jj,1) = 255;
            I2(ii,jj,2) = 255;
            I2(ii,jj,3) = 255;

        else
            I2(ii,jj,1) = 0;
            I2(ii,jj,2) = 0;
            I2(ii,jj,3) = 0;
        end
    end
end
A1 = im2bw(I2); % change image I2 into binart. Here image is not binary because it contains 255 values not 1.
A1 = not(A1);   % for invert the binary image
I4 = imfill(A1,'holes');
I5 = bwareaopen(I4,800);
toc;
```

**The Second script is**

```
tic;
I2 = imread('28.jpg');
II = I2;
 A = im2double(I2); % convert image into double so that subtraction can be -ve also
divi = (A(:,:,3)./A(:,:,2)); % b/g ratio

for ii = 1:size(I2,1)
    for jj = 1:size(I2,2)
ddd = divi(ii,jj); 
if I2(ii,jj,1) < 80   % to remove black color pixels and others noise
    I2(ii,jj,1) = 255; 
    I2(ii,jj,2) = 255;
    I2(ii,jj,3) = 255;
elseif ddd > 0.9 && ddd < 1.1 
    I2(ii,jj,1) = 0;
    I2(ii,jj,2) = 0;
    I2(ii,jj,3) = 0;
else
   I2(ii,jj,1) = 255;
    I2(ii,jj,2) = 255;
    I2(ii,jj,3) = 255; 
end
    end 
end
A1 = im2bw(I2); % change image I2 into binart. Here image is not binary because it contains 255 values not 1.
A1 = not(A1);   % for invert the binary image
 % to fill region 
I4 = imfill(A1,'holes');
 I3 = bwareaopen(I4,1600);
 toc;
```

The first script took only **0.19 seconds** while the second script took **0.36 seconds**. In both script I'm performing mathematical opertion.

In first I did subtraction `ca = I2(:,:,3) - (I2(:,:,1)/3)- (I2(:,:,2)/3);` while in 2nd script I calculated ratio `divi = (A(:,:,3)./A(:,:,2));` . After this, in both cases, I proceed pixel by pixel.

So, according to me, time should not vary too much. But it is nearly double for the 2nd script.

**I want to know why it is so? It will be better for me if anyone can explain it mathematically also.**

*Image I used is:*
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: the MATLAB version is the most important part of your question! Which version are you using?

Comment: @Ander Biguri When I used MATLAB 2014b, timing was 1.8 seconds for 1st and 2.7 for second script. But when I tried in Matlab 16a its timing was as mentioned in question.

Comment: As Alex said: do not time the image read and repeat the same calculation 10 times, averaging the time it took for solid results.

Comment: Do you know why so timing difference between MATLAB 2014 and 2016?

Comment: 1) your timing is wrong. Please consider reading the comment I made. 2) JIT compiler has been improved, especially for for loops, in the last versions

Comment: Also, considering you're doing different operations in the two scripts, it's not strange that timings differ.

Answer (score 1):

I could not reproduce the same behavior (using Matlab2016b).

For me *script 1* takes **0.013 s** and *script 2* **0.016 s**. I started measuring after reading the image.

As a general rule, when bench-marking some behavior repeat it multiple times. One execution can vary a lot.

Comment: When I used MATLAB 2014b, the timing was 1.8 seconds for 1st and 2.7 for second script. But when I tried in Matlab 16a its timing was as mentioned in question. What are the possible reasons for this timing difference? What changes occur between MATLAB 2014 and 2016.

Comment: @NaseebGill: Yes, many changes occurred between those releases. And many more since. They keep tweaking the JIT (just-in-time compiler) and improving performance.